# Angular library PROD build throws exception

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I have an Angular 9 library which I would like to push to registry.

When I run `ng build <my-lib>`, it builds correctly, but it complains about Ivy:

```
******************************************************************************
It is not recommended to publish Ivy libraries to NPM repositories.
Read more here: https://v9.angular.io/guide/ivy#maintaining-library-compatibility
******************************************************************************
```

and it's impossible to push due to this:

> ERROR: Trying to publish a package that has been compiled by Ivy. This is not allowed.
>   Please delete and rebuild the package, without compiling with Ivy, before attempting to publish.

When I run `ng build <my-lib> --prod`, it throws an error about `[hidden]`:

> [error] Error: Can't bind to 'hidden' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-content'.
>   1. If 'hidden' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
>   2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("][hidden] = "!active">")

I verified and all my modules import `CommonModule`.

Why is it building fine without `--prod`, but when I want to build it for `--prod` it complains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use directive [hidden] which not exist in your app.

Register that directive in your module or use `*ngIf` or `[ngClass]` which i assume is what you expected from "hidden" to do